# How to log user in via local storage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

To access the content of my app (under ionic), my users have to log in first. Sometimes, the app crashes and it "logs the user out" (well in fact it loses the session but firebase has the user still logged in).

I would like to use the local storage method but I am having a hard time understanding how to put the code together.

I found this tutorial here : [Use local storage to login user](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/06/saving-data-with-ionicframework/)

And here is my controller :

```
    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("username"));
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("password"));
console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("uid"));



  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function(userLogin) {
        if($document[0].getElementById("user_name").value != "" && $document[0].getElementById("user_pass").value != ""){
          // Setup the loader

          window.localStorage.setItem("username", $document[0].getElementById("user_name").value);
          window.localStorage.setItem("password", $document[0].getElementById("user_pass").value);

          $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Loading',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 200,
            showDelay: 0
          });
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userLogin.username, userLogin.password).then(function() {

          window.localStorage.setItem("uid", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

          var userId = window.localStorage.getItem("uid");
          firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId + '/currentBusiness/').update({
            name: "No current business arround",
            description: "Seems there's nothing arround...",

            })

                      $state.go("tab.account");

        }, function(error) {
          // An error happened.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;

          if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-email') {
             alert('Enter a valid email.');
             $timeout(function () {

               $ionicLoading.hide();
             }, 1000);
             return false;

          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
             alert('Incorrect password.');
             $timeout(function () {

               $ionicLoading.hide();
             }, 1000);
             return false;

          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/argument-error') {
             alert('Password must be string.');
             $timeout(function () {

               $ionicLoading.hide();
             }, 1000);
             return false;

          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found') {
             alert('No such user found.');
             $timeout(function () {

               $ionicLoading.hide();
             }, 1000);
             return false;

          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/too-many-requests') {
             alert('Too many failed login attempts, please try after sometime.');
             $timeout(function () {

               $ionicLoading.hide();
             }, 1000);
             return false;

          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/network-request-failed') {
             alert('Request timed out, please try again.');
             $timeout(function () {

               $ionicLoading.hide();
             }, 1000);
             return false;

          }else {
             alert(errorMessage);
             $timeout(function () {

               $ionicLoading.hide();
             }, 1000);
             return false;

          }
        });
    }else{
        alert('Please enter email and password');
        return false;
    }//end check client username password
  };// end $scope.doLogin()

  // Create a callback which logs the current auth state


  if (window.localStorage.getItem("username") !== null && window.localStorage.getItem("password") !== null) {
      $state.go("tab.account");
  } else {
    console.log("wooooooo");
  }
```

Any help to integrate both ?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what problem you are having and what specific question you'd like addressed.

Comment: Hello, I would like to integrate the local storage for 1) store the data of email and password and 2) automatically log in the user if the data are already stored. From the link I wrote...

Comment: Ok, that's what you want, but as I asked, what problem are you having?

Comment: I updated my code with the actual tutorial I found and I try it, it works perfectly on browser. 
However, on Android, if I kill the app, not only it doesn't automatically logs me in but also if I try to enter my credentials, it doesn't process the log in either and stays spinning forever. Am I doing something wrong ? PS : I have no way to debug on Android via a console...

Comment: Don't store passwords in localstorage, plugins can access it.

Comment: Then I literally have no way to remember my users because the native way via Firebase doesn't work either on Android. Like a charm on browser and iOS but no way on Android. So each time the user opens the app on Android, he has to log back in. What a hassle ?

Comment: This is usually done by HttpOnly cookies or by token https://auth0.com/blog/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/